# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int16' to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, casting, .net

I encounter the following exception in a LINQ query .

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int16' to type 'System.String'.

---

```
 var query = from t in dt.AsEnumerable()
                        select new
                        {
                            sys_db= t.Field<Int16>("process_id").ToString() + "|" + t.Field<string>("db_code").ToString(),
                            process_name = t.Field<string>("process_name").ToString()
                        };
```

---

Why this problem appear and how to fix it ?

Comment: sys_db= t.Field<Int16>("process_id").ToString() + "|" + t.Field<string>("db_code").ToString(), Why you have written Int16? Because that you need to change to string.... as the text is getting merged

Comment: your `db_code` is type of `int`

Comment: `Specified cast is not valid.`

Comment: What is the data type of "db_code" field? It must be Int16

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This

```
t.Field<string>("db_code").ToString()
```

perhaps should be this:

```
t.Field<short>("db_code").ToString()
```

or equivalent

```
t.Field<Int16>("db_code").ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why this problem appear

This appears because you are trying to read an Int16 field to a string, which is not allowed

> how to fix it

First of all identify the field which is actually an int16 and you are reading as string. From your code it is most probably this field

```
t.Field<string>("db_code")
```

you need to change it to

```
t.Field<Int16>("db_code")
```